# Iterating through files and saving results

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Since I am learning python please can someone give me some advices or which python package to use to improve my code:

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


source = pd.read_table("data1.dat", delim_whitespace=True,header=None)

v = source.iloc[:,0]
f = source.iloc[:,1]

w1 = np.average(f[(v>40) & (v<42)])
w2 = np.average(f[(v>44) & (v<45)])
w3 = np.average(f[(v>50) & (v<52)])
```

I need to run this code on 4 datasets (they have the same shape).

How I can loop (or maybe loop is not needed) through my folder and run my code on data1.dat, data2.dat, data3.dat and data4.dat.

After this is done, I would like to save those results into one table which looks like this:

d1 d2 d3 d4
w1 w1 w1 w1
w2 w2 w2 w2
w3 w3 w3 w3

(d1 d2 d3 d4 is header or name of each column).

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at itertools, a very powerfull library for handeling iterable sets.

Comment: `itertools` is way overkill for this simple task.  Essentially, grab the paths to each file (`glob`, for example), and use something like `for f in files: …`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the files are on your Desktop

```
path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop'
```

Iterate over all files in the path

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.dat')):
    source = pd.read_table(file, delim_whitespace=True,header=None)

    v = source.iloc[:,0]
    f = source.iloc[:,1]

    w1 = np.average(f[(v>40) & (v<42)])
    w2 = np.average(f[(v>44) & (v<45)])
    w3 = np.average(f[(v>50) & (v<52)])
```

Comment: Excellent this part is solved :) ... now just to figure out how to save the data.

Comment: Great. Feel free to mark as answered if this answers your question and upvote the answer :)

Comment: @user16454053 - Saving the data is the easy bit.  Since your data is in `numpy.array` structures, have a look at the `numpy.save()` method. This allows the storing of `numpy` array data to serialised files. And its inverse method `numpy.load()`.  [Docs here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)